# $\ell_0$-norm of $\|Ax-b\|$ for a given $A,b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times c$ matrix and $b\geq 0$ (element-wise) be a given $n\times 1$ vector. $A$ has following properties

- $n>c$ and $rank(A)=c$.
- Any choice of $c$ rows of $A$ is linearly independent.
- $A$ is element-wise positive.

  *Question: Let $x$ be any given non-negative vector such that $\|x\|_0\geq 1$. Is
  $$\|Ax-b\|_0\leq c$$ where $\|\cdot\|_0$ denotes the $\ell_0$-norm*

Comment: @user1551 udpated

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true. E.g.
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1\\ 1&1\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{\frac23\\ \frac13}-\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1}\right\|_0
=\left\|\frac13\pmatrix{-1\\ -2\\ 0\\ 1}\right\|_0
=3>c=2.
$$
Note that in this example, $b\not\in\operatorname{ran}(A)$ and $x=A^+b$.

Comment: nice to see you after a long time. This requires $b$ to lie in column-space of $A$, if that is not true, then will this still hold?